# how to convert certain values for one of the column of dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Say there is a data frame df

```
A     B

0   Aus Brazilian Restaurant

1   Aus Gym

2   Aus Zoo

3   Aus Restaurant Thai

4   Aus Australian restaurant
```

Need to convert it to

```
A     B

0   Aus Restaurant

1   Aus Gym

2   Aus Zoo

3   Aus Restaurant

4   Aus Restaurant
```

code to create dataframe:

```
temp = {'A':5*['Aus'],'B':['Brazilian Restaurant','Gym','Zoo','Restaurant Thai','Australian restaurant']
     }

temp

df = pd.DataFrame(temp)

df
```

This is the code in Ipython

Comment: Please tidy up your code markup - the examples are unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. Posting here, in case it is of use for someone.

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
if ('Restaurant' in df.loc[i,'B'] or 'restaurant' in df.loc[i,'B']):
    df.loc[i,'B']='Restaurant'
```

df